# Is it ok to do a type-converting comparison when checking if something is a string?

Tags: javascript

Since `typeof someVariable === string` will not return true for strings that were instantiated with `new String()`, is it ok to do this:

```
if(typeof someVariable == 'string') {
  // do something
}
```

To make sure that the comparison will catch those cases as well, or will such a comparison have unintended side effects?

Comment: I don't understand the question -- `typeof someVariable === string` will throw an error if the variable `string` is not defined and `typeof someVariable == 'string'` will evaluate to false for strings made with `new String()`.

Comment: you have to do === 'string', since string will be treated as a variable.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz: No you don't, there's exactly no difference between `== "string"` and `=== "string"` when you're checking against `typeof anything`, because `typeof` will return a string, guaranteed, and so type coercion doesn't come into it and `==` and `===` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since typeof someVariable === string will not return true for strings that were instantiated with new String(), is it ok to do this:

It's *okay*, but it won't give you `true` for string objects, it'll still be `false`. It's not the `==` vs. `===` that matters, it's what you're checking.

If you want to reliably check for both string primitives and string objects, then:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(someVariable) === "[object String]")
```

...is how you do that. It works because if `someVariable` is a string object, that's the string that [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring) is guaranteed to return for it. If `someVariable` is a string *primitive*, then either using it as the `thisArg` in a `Function#call` (loose mode) or the `Object.prototype.toString` function itself (strict mode) will coerce it to a string object before figuring out what it is. Either way, you get back `"[object String]"`.

More about this *(on my blog)*: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)